# Mean pairwise Pearson correlation

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, intraclass-correlation

Consider a set of $M$ multidimensional observations $X=\{x_i\}_{i=1..M}$ for $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^N$, and define $c_{ij}$ to be the Pearson correlation coefficient between $x_i$ and $x_j$.

Is there a simple expression or useful approximation for the mean pairwise Pearson correlation $C=\frac{1}{M^2}\sum_{ij}c_{ij}$?

Alternatively, is there a simple expression for other measure which is similar in spirit to the "mean pairwise Pearson correlation", perhaps defined differently than $C$ above?

(This is motivated by the fact that if $c_{ij}$ was square Euclidean distance, then we had $C=2Var(X)$ and thus I wonder if there is a similar result for Pearson correlation.)

Comment: Since the $x_i$ are $N$-vectors, what do you mean by _the_ Pearson correlation coefficient between $x_i$ and $x_j$? Are you considering two random variables $(A,B)$ taking on $N$ equally likely values $(x_{i,k},x_{j,k}), 1 \leq k \leq N$ and taking $c_{i,j}$ as the Pearson correlation coefficient $\rho_{A,B}$?

Comment: I mean $\rho(x,y)=(x-\bar{x})^T(y-\bar{y})/\sqrt{(x-\bar{x})^T(x-\bar{x})(y-\bar{y})^T(y-\bar{y})}$ where I wrote x rather than $x_i $ and y rather than $x_j$ for brevity.

Comment: Your $\rho(x,y)$ is _exactly_ what I would get if I were to compute $\rho_{A,B}$ in my notation. I suspect that it is unlikely that a closed form exists for the average value of the Pearson correlation coefficients, but the average value of the _covariances_ (essentially proportional to $(x-\bar{x})^T(y-\bar{y})$) is easily calculated.

Comment: Ok, then if $\tilde{x_i}=(x_i-\bar{x_i})/\sqrt{x_i^Tx_i}$ then $C=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j}\tilde{x_i}^T\tilde{x_j}=(\sum_i \tilde{x_i}/N)^T (\sum_j \tilde{x_j}/N)=||\mu||^2$ for $\mu=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i \tilde{x_i}$.